# Show url attibuts in twig

Tags: 8, theming, routes

I have this in my routing page

```
function_adh_apport.adh_apport:
  path: '/collecte/apports/{date}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\function_adh_apport\Controller\RapportsController::filtrer'
    date: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    date: \d+
```

I got this url : ../web/collecte/apports/2016

but now, i'm trying to show in twig the value of {date}

So i do this in twig :

```
{{ path('function_adh_apport.adh_apport', { 'date': apports.date}) }}
```

but it return "../web/collecte/apports" and not just "2016"

Comment: apports.date is probably empty or null it should returns, make a {{ dump(apports.date) }} in your template to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, {{ dump(apports.date) }} return NULL

Answer (score 0):

I have do a preprocess function in my file ".module" like this

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page()
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['get']['date'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS::filter($_GET['date']);
}
```

but not sure that correct

Answer (score 0):

According to your preprocess :

> `$vars['get']['date'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS::filter($_GET['date']);`

Your template should be :

```
{{ path('function_adh_apport.adh_apport', { 'date': get.date }) }}
```

PS : better to use `\Drupal::request()->query->get('date');` than `$_GET['date']`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it doesn't work when i {{ dump(apports.date) }} i got 'NULL'. and my url is always "./web/collecte/apports".  I have change the preprocess and my template :/

Comment: your preprocess is adding `$vars['get']['date']`, if you need something in `apports.date`, you should do `$vars['apports']['date'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS::filter($_GET['date']);`

Note that this apports.date will be present in `page.html.twig`.

Comment: Sry, i have same result :/

Comment: I think you are mistaking elsewhere, how is called your template file ? how is called your module ? is your function correctly prefixed with your module's name.

Comment: So in my controller i call my template  `$build ['theme'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'liste-adh2');` in my routing i called my function "filtrer" from my controller and in my file ".module" with my template i have add the preprocess function

Comment: I think you are not using the nice preprocess function. Enable twig debug in `services.yml`, and inspect code with your browser to locate the preprocess you need to use. Probably something like MYMODULE_preprocess_liste_adh2() .

Comment: I will check this. But i saw in my webprofiler debug in "Request" all atributs from my page for example _route,  _ route_params and i can see "date" in attribut with value "2016"

Comment: Are you trying to get a value for url (i.e. 2016) `/collecte/apports/2016` with $_GET['date'] ? this won't work. Right way should be `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('date')` in this case.

Comment: Yes, just trying to show the {date} in twig. I have try your solution and sry it's again Null. I think it's my bad i do something wrong